# How to get the coordinates of a vertex of a tetrahedron with only the lenghts of the edges?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need the coordinates of E and have the coordinates of A, B, C and the distance to them from E.
It should be possible, in 2D I got it like [image: this] with a rotation matrix.
But in 3D the angles of the edges are not parallel to axis so I cant really use the same principle can I ?

[image: See]

Comment: One way is to write out the three distance equations in $x,y,z$ (the coordinates of $E$) and then solve for each coordinate.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that? Which distance equations ?

Comment: The distance between two points in space is $$\sqrt{ (x_1 -x_2)^2 + (y_1 -y_2)^2 + (z_1 - z_2)^2 }$$

Comment: i see :) but isnt that a non linear equation system then ?

Comment: Exactly, which means there may be multiple points which are candidates for $E$, so there’s not enough information to determine one fixed point.

Comment: Essentially, you’re computing the [intersection of three spheres](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/786489/265466).

Comment: what if I say that E is always above the plain of ABC ? would that help ?

Comment: Not necessarily. You may want to refer to amd’s comment.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @amd and @Tavish !

The problem is often not to find a solution but to ask the right question.
Indeed I was really just searching for the intersection of 3 spheres and wikipedia had the answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_range_multilateration#Three_Cartesian_dimensions,_three_measured_slant_ranges

Here is a simple implementation in python:

```
def calculate_position(distances):

# Find the intersections of the three spheres created with three radii
# Implementation based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_range_multilateration

A = (0, 0, 0)
B = (10, 0, 0)
C = (5, 10, 0)
V_SQ = C[0] ** 2 + C[1] ** 2
r1, r2, r3 = distances

x = (r1 ** 2 - r2 ** 2 + B[0] ** 2) / (2 * B[0])
y = (r1 ** 2 - r3 ** 2 + V_SQ - 2 * C[0] * x) / (2 * C[1])
z1 = sqrt(r1 ** 2 - x ** 2 - y ** 2)
if z1 >= 0:
    return x, y, z1
return x, y, -z1
```