# Find a point using multilateration or triangulation

Tags: coordinate-systems

Suppose we have 3 points in a 3d coordinate system with the following locations.

A=(100,0,0)
B=(0,100,100)
C=(0,0,100)

If there is a 4th point D, where the distances from A, B, and C are known, can I find the coordinates of point D?  If so, how would I find the coordinates?  In my particular application, only one of the two points could be valid and it would be obvious which one.

Comment: It would narrow $D$ down to two possible points, one if you're lucky. Think of $A,B,C$ as a plane. If $D$ is on the plane, then you have it. If $D$ is off the plane, there are two solutions, one on each side of the plane that are mirrors of each other.

Comment: Thanks.  Updated my question to request the actual solution, not just the feasibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the given distances are $a,b,c$. Then the point you seek is at the intersection of three spheres: the sphere of radius $a$ centered at $A$, the sphere of radius $b$ centered at $B$, and the sphere of radius $c$ centered at $C$. There will (usually) be two intersection points, but you say it will be obvious which of the two is the desired one.

To intersect three spheres, look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562240/how-to-find-the-intersection-of-three-spheres-full-solutions) or this page on [trilateration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration)